# Как написать API без знаний в Веб?

Tags: php, python

Дело в том, что мне нужно для сохранения и получения обратно пара значений(переменных) в `андроид` приложении. Но так как я смыслю в `веб разработке` немного в замешательстве. Мне не нужен сайт, главное чтобы мог сохранять данные в базе и работать с `API`.

Хотелось спросить обязательно ли мне изучить `php` чтобы написать `API` или есть уже готовые примеры которые подходят моим нуждам?

Comment: Не обязательно использовать PHP. Почему бы не написать его на java?

Comment: Любой язык пригодный для написания бэкенда. PHP, Python, NodeJS, Java, GoLang, etc

Comment: Может скинете какую ссылку, как выше упоминал, не имел дело с веб. Нужен хостинг и далее что?

Comment: Мне просто нужен быстрый вариант. Не резонно просто возится неделями.

Comment: Если я правильно понял, нужно настроить CGI/WSGI и запросы API будут попадать на Ваш скрипт. Пишите его на чем угодно, вывод будет идти как ответ сервера (тут внимательно - на том-же Питухоне сначала надо отправлять заголовок)

Comment: Извините, но про какой скрипт идет речь?)

Comment: Вы хотите написать API или его использовать? Если надо написать веб-API, то достаточно сделать ворота CGI и запросы на функции API будут попадать на Вашу прогу

Comment: Чтобы написать мне нужно понять что за CGI и все такое и время потеряю. Поэтому ищу уже готовые решения, библиотеки.

Comment: CGI выходит за уровень библиотек... Так просто "взять" - не получится.

Comment: Для обкатки клиент-сайд не нужны никакие серверные языки. Кладёшь на сервере готовые json файлы ответов в нужные папки. Потом нанимаешь программиста.

Comment: По поводу того, что такое API: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/API

Comment: @PaulVergeev, вы походу вопрос не читали. Удачи!

Comment: @TITAN прочтите, все же, статью!

Comment: @PaulVergeev, ок, а вы вопрос!

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно проверить работу Android приложения (сохранение данных в базе не обязательно), то подойдет сервис [apiary.io](https://apiary.io/how-apiary-works). Сделаете мокап и проверите ваше приложение.

Если все-таки необходимо создание и получение данных из базы, то придется настроить тестовый сервер. Рекомендую установить поднять [LAMP на Amazon EC2 из уже собранного имиджа](https://eu-central-1.console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/v2/home?region=eu-central-1#LaunchInstanceWizard:).

Потом установить composer и поставить любой микрофреймворк, например Slim и простую ORM, например idiORM. Но программировать придется в этом случае, хотя и не много.